# What is this HDMI connector?

Tags: identification, connector, surface-mount, hdmi, through-hole

I'm trying to identify this HDMI connector.

The marking on it says TCF but I haven't found a manufacturer with that name or any other info based on that. I went through the Digikey, Mouser and Molex catalogues to find a visual match but vertical HDMI connectors seem to be rare.

The height of the shield is approximately 15mm (without the 3 ground pins).

Does anybody know what that TCF mark stands for or where I could find a compatible replacement?

[image]

[image: 19 SMD pins and 3 through hole ground pins]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit more searching and there's a similar part [HDMI-19P-VS5](https://www.contactswitch.com/en/product_detail.aspx?id=6469) from "Contact Technology Corp", which again from the [datasheet](https://www.contactswitch.com/en/download.aspx?id=6469) gives a height of 15mm:

[image: Dimensions withe height of 15mm]

This one looks like quite a good fit - the drawing in the datasheet shows three little bumps in the bottom left corner of the connector which match perfectly with the plastic moulding in your image.

The joint in the shell (where the two ends of the folded metal meet) is on the correct side of the connector (pin side).

---

Another possibility is [HMA19XXXS05X30](http://www.fsconn.com/goods_show.aspx?id=190) from FSConn or some similar part. The [datasheet](http://www.fsconn.com/upload/201711/29/201711291111294750.pdf) gives the dimension as 15mm above the PCB:

[image: Dimensions of connector]

This one isn't a prefect match as the fold on the shell based on images of it is on the other side (opposite from pins).

There may be other such suppliers or makers, but this was the first I found with the correct height (most are much shorter) - searched for "vertical HDMI 15mm".